# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC app via sftp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sftp, web-deployment

My university allows me to deploy my web app only via sftp. Visual Studio deployment tool does not support sftp. What's the best way to solve that problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could publish your app to the folder and then upload whole folder using SFTP client like FileZilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the VS publish tool.

For a ASP.NET MVC site, you need to upload contents of the project folder, except for anything that will have been compiled... Open Visual Studio, compile your project, then upload via FTP.

Upload the bin folder with the compiled dll's, along with any views, scripts (anything that will be served to the client), and config files in the folder structure inside the project directory.

Basically, upload anything that doesn't have a .cs file extension. The exact files will vary based on your project. (You don't need .pdb files, or your .csproj file either)

If a folder contains only .cs files, you don't need it since it'll be compiled in the dll's (like the Controllers folder). If a folder contains anything else (.cshtml, .js, .css, etc) then upload it.

This can all be done via an FTP client like CuteFTP, FileZilla, Cyberduck etc. Just connect to your server and upload to the directory that is set up for your application in IIS.